# PHP count of occurrences of characters of a string within another string

Tags: php, string, count, character

Let's say I have two strings.

```
$needle = 'AGUXYZ';
$haystack = 'Agriculture ID XYZ-A';
```

I want to count how often characters that are in `$needle` occur in `$haystack`. In `$haystack`, there are the characters 'A' (twice), 'X', 'Y' and 'Z', all of which are in the needle, thus the result is supposed to be 5 (case-sensitive).

Is there any function for that in PHP or do I have to program it myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can calculate the length of the original string and the length of the string without these characters. The differences between them is the number of matches.

Basically,

```
$needle = 'AGUXYZ';
$haystack = 'Agriculture ID XYZ-A';
```

Here is the part that does the work. In one line.

```
$count = strlen($haystack) - strlen(str_replace(str_split($needle), '', $haystack));
```

**Explanation:** The first part is self-explanatory. The second part is the length of the string without the characters in the `$needle` string. This is done by replacing each occurrences of any characters inside the `$needle` with a blank string.

To do this, we split `$needle` into an array, once character for each item, using [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split). Then pass it to [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace). It replaces each occurence of any items in the `$search` array with a blank string.

Echo it out,

```
echo "Count = $count\n";
```

you get:

> [Count = 5](http://codepad.org/o4n72R3U)

Answer (score 6):

Try this;

```
function count_occurences($char_string, $haystack, $case_sensitive = true){
    if($case_sensitive === false){
        $char_string = strtolower($char_string);
        $haystack = strtolower($haystack);
    }

    $characters = str_split($char_string);
    $character_count = 0;
    foreach($characters as $character){
        $character_count = $character_count + substr_count($haystack, $character);
    }
    return $character_count;
}
```

To use;

```
$needle = 'AGUXYZ';
$haystack = 'Agriculture ID XYZ-A';
print count_occurences($needle, $haystack);
```

You can set the third parameter to `false` to ignore case.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in function that handles character sets, but you simply use the [substr_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function in a loop as such:

```
<?php
    $sourceCharacters = str_split('AGUXYZ');
    $targetString = 'Agriculture ID XYZ-A';
    $occurrenceCount = array();

    foreach($sourceCharacters as $currentCharacter) {
        $occurrenceCount[$currentCharacter] = substr_count($targetString, $currentCharacter);
    }

    print_r($occurrenceCount);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific method to do this, but this built in method can surely help you:

```
$count = substr_count($haystack , $needle);
```

**edit:** I just reported the general `substr_count` method..in your particular case you need to call it for each character inside $needle (thanks @Alan Whitelaw)

Comment: This will only look for `AGUXYZ` in the haystack as php.net/substr-count shows `$needle` to be a string

Comment: This is the generic example of the substr_count... to achieve that particular result you need to check every char of the $needle string :) ..sorry I didn't explained it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in the character distribution, you could use a Regex

```
echo preg_match_all("/[$needle]/", $haystack, $matches);
```

which returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or `FALSE` if an error occurred. The [solution offered by @thai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736058/php-count-of-occurrences-of-characters-of-a-string-within-another-string/4736219#4736219) above should be significantly faster though.

---

If the character distribution is of any importance, you can use [`count_chars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php):

```
$needle = 'AGUXYZ';
$haystack = 'Agriculture ID XYZ-A';

$occurences = array_intersect_key(
    count_chars($haystack, 1),
    array_flip(
        array_map('ord', str_split($needle))
    )
);
```

The result would be an array with keys being the ASCII values of the character.
You can then iterate over it with

```
foreach($occurences as $char => $amount) {
    printf("There is %d occurences of %s\n", $amount, chr($char));
}
```

You could still pass the `$occurences` array to [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to calculate the total.

Comment: `$matches` doesn't need to be declared in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

[substr_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) will get you close. However, it will not do individual characters. So you could loop over each character in `$needle` and call this function while summing the counts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP function [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count the number of instances of a character in a string. It would be trivial to extend it for multiple characters:

```
function substr_multi_count ($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0, $length = null) {
    $ret = 0;

    if ($length === null) {
        $length = strlen($haystack) - $offset;
    }

    for ($i = strlen($needle); $i--; ) {
        $ret += substr_count($haystack, $needle, $offset, $length);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

1. split the string to chars (`str_split`), and then
2. use  `array_count_values` to get an array of characters with the respective number of occurrences.

Code:

```
$needle = 'AGUXYZ';
$string = "asdasdadas asdadas asd asdsd";
$array_chars = str_split($string);
$value_count = array_count_values($array_chars);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($needle); $i++)
    echo $needle[$i]. " is occur " . 
         ($value_count[$needle[$i]] ? $value_count[$needle[$i]] : '0')." times";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a recursive method to overcome this:

```
function countChar($str){

  if(strlen($str) == 0) return 0;

  if(substr($str,-1) == "x") return 1 + countChar(substr($str,0,-1));

  return 0 + countChar(substr($str,0,-1));

}

  echo countChar("xxSR"); // 2
  echo countChar("SR"); // 0
  echo countChar("xrxrpxxx"); // 5
```

Comment: This answer does not provide the required process.  This checks for a statically declared string.