# mysql regex return containing

Tags: mysql

I'm new to regular expressions and after searching and experimenting I cannot find a solution. I want to search a database with words. The search pattern contains possibly letters that should be present in the returned words. Example pattern: `pale` should return word containing 'p' and / or 'a' and / or 'l' and / or 'e':

Possible words (if in database): `pal`, `lea`, `epa`, `pale`, `elap` etc ...

My question is how to build a regular expression that can perform the above.

Regards.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE word RLIKE '^[pale]+$'
```

A regular expression to honor the letter counts would look like:

```
^(p?(a?(l?e?|e?l?)|l?(a?|e?)|e?(a?lf?|l?a?))|a?(p?(l?e?|e?l?)|l?(p?e?|e?p?)|e?(p?l?|l?p?))|l?(a?(p?e?|e?p?)|p?(a?e?|e?a?)|e?(a?p?|p?a?))|e?(p?(a?l?|l?a?)|a?(p?l?|l?p?)|l?(a?p?|p?a?)))$
```

As you can see, there's an exponential growth in the size of the regexp based on the length of the input.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it almost works but words containing multiple 'p' for instance are also returned, 'appell'. Is there a way to restrict the query to honor the letter count in the pattern?

Comment: No, I don't think regular expressions can do that without combinatorial explosion in the size of the regexp.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. I ended up using your expression and on a second run removed all words where the lettercount for each letter was exceeded. Working great now. Thanks again.

Comment: A beautiful way to calculate the count of a certain character in a string:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736058/php-count-of-occurrences-of-characters-of-a-string-within-another-string/4736219#4736219